# How to load a file from a database into Solr

Tags: solr, solrj

I am using the following Groovy code to load a file stored in MongoDB for indexing in Solr. (I have already created a file object that contains the file contents as well as the file name):

```
ContentStreamUpdateRequest up = new ContentStreamUpdateRequest("/update/extract")

def tempFile = new File("temp/temp-${file.name}")
tempFile.append(file.file) //file.file references the byte[] of the file
//append call writes the file to disk

up.addFile(tempFile, "application/octet-stream")

up.setParam("literal.id", file.id.toString())
up.setParam("literal.name", "ConsultantFile")
up.setParam("literal.fileName_s", file.name)
up.setParam("literal.creator_s", file.createdBy?.lastFirstName)

up.setAction(AbstractUpdateRequest.ACTION.COMMIT, true, true)

server.request(up) //server object is the shared handle to the Solr instance

tempFile.delete()
```

So, I already have a byte array of the file, but I am writing it to disk so I can use the addFile method. Then, as cleanup, I delete the file on disk. It works, but it's stupid.

I tried the following code in place of the up.addFile(), but it throws a "non ok status:500 message:Server Error"

```
def stringFile = new String(file.file, "UTF-8")
def stream = new ContentStreamBase.StringStream(stringFile)
up.addContentStream(stream)
```

What's the best way to index a file I already have in memory without having to write it to disk as an intermediate step?

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the [addContentStream](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api-4_0_0-BETA/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/request/ContentStreamUpdateRequest.html#addContentStream%28org.apache.solr.common.util.ContentStream%29) method which should allow you to use the stream.

Also, if you have a web interface to expose the file you can check for [Sending_documents_to_Solr](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler#Sending_documents_to_Solr)